# Converting NSString to float, the result is wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is the code:

```
NSString *val = @"51785239";
unsigned long long valFromFloat = 0L;
unsigned long long valFromLL = 0L;
valFromFloat = [val floatValue];
valFromLL = [val integerValue];
```

I was testing this code, the result is: valFromFloat = 51785240.0, valFromLL = 51785239.

Why valFromFloat is 51785240.0? I thought it should be 51785239.0.

Please, someone can explain it?

Comment: `float` has limited precision. BTW - why would you use `floatValue` and assign to a `long long`? Why not use `longLongValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused over floating point vs. integer types, and misunderstand floating point precision.

> Why valFromFloat is 51785240.0?

It isn't. `valFromFloat` is a variable of integer type, specifically `unsigned long long`, so its value certainly has no decimal fractional part.

The statement:

```
valFromFloat = [val floatValue];
```

first calls a method to parse (interpret) the string value `val` as a `float` value, which is the low precision floating-point type. That `float` value is then converted to an `unsigned long long` value and stored into `valFromFloat`.

Try:

```
float asFloat = [val floatValue];
double asDouble = [val doubleValue];
int asInt = [val intValue];
NSLog(@"float: %f | double: %f | int: %d", asFloat, asDouble, asInt);
```

and see what you get. Then lookup floating-point precision and the difference between binary floating-point, such as the types `float` and `double`, and decimal floating-point types, such as `NSDecimal` and `NSDecimalNumber`.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

The float 
The screenshot from **MacTypes.h**.
[image]

As we can see the float 【Float32】 is 32 bit IEEE float:  1 sign bit, 8 exponent bits, 23 fraction bits.

And we can get the bellow images from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

[image]

[image]

Then we can convert the string to float as bellow:

```
51785239(10)=11000101100010111000010111(2)
```

Also IEEE 754 binary32 format requires that you represent real values in [image] format,  so that 11000101100010111000010111 is shifted to the right by 25 digits to become [image]

From which we deduce:

The exponent is 25 (and in the biased form it is therefore 152 = 1001 1000)
The fraction is 1000101100010111000011000 (looking to the right 25 bits of the binary point whitch is rounding to 1000101100010111000011000)

thus:

[image]

Comment: Why the down vote folks? Yes it lacks explanation, but it does precisely explain the result. 孙博弘 - you do need to add explanation to your answers, many readers will have no idea what you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
valFromFloat = [val floatValue];
```

to

```
valFromFloat = [val doubleValue];
```

(and think about what a float is).

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *string_val =@"51785239.65";
float float_val=[string_val floatValue];
```

Comment: 1) Don't post code-only answers. Explain what was wrong and how your answer solves the issue. 2) This answer doesn't even fix the issue.